# Difference between universal and existential statement for isosceles triangle.

Tags: triangles, proof-explanation

I know the obvious that for a universal statement usually it's: "For all [...]"
and existential it's: "There exists [...]".

But this statement doesn't put it that obvious.

I have a feeling that is it a universal.

This is the statement:

> **Proposition**. Let $XYZ$ be a right triangle with sides of length $x$ and $y$ and hypotenuse $z$. If the area is $z^2 /4$, then the triangle is isosceles.

Could someone shine some light on this please?

Comment: is it because of the  _Let_ ? Which makes it a universal statement?

Answer (score 1):

You're right. The theorem means exactly the same as:

> **Proposition**. For every right triangle $XYZ$ with sides of length $x$ and $y$ and hypotenuse $z$, it holds that if the area is $z^2 /4$, then the triangle is isosceles.

The wording "Let $\langle\text{variable}\rangle$ be a $\langle\text{something}\rangle$" is just an alternative way to phrase "for all...", which is often used when stating theorems in order to make the prose flow better (because "Let ..." makes a complete sentence that you can follow with a full stop, whereas "For all ..." is a dependent clause that needs to be joined to the main statement by a comma).

Formally there's no difference between the two.

---

Beware, however, of the difference to the phrasing

> Let $k$ be $\frac{n+3}2 + p$.

which might appear inside a proof. The latter is neither a universal or an existential, but a *definition*: It simply gives a name to something that it is *already* fully clear what is. Note that in this case there's no "a" after "be", which signals that nobody has any choice for what to make $k$ means -- it has to be the precise number that is $\frac{n+3}2+p$, and nothing else.

Comment: Ok, great! So in other words, the triangle XYZ is being quantified here.

Comment: @Reine: Yes -- the proposition says that as the user of the proposition _you_ get to choose which triangle you're going to apply it to.